# change property of javascript obj later

Tags: javascript, function, properties

In my main template file i have this

```
var Product = function(){  
   this.is_active = true,
   this.is_bom_enabled = false;
};
```

Now later i need to modify the `Product`, mainly i need to add more properties.

I tried

```
Product.someOtherThing = value; // only work for `Product` and not for new instances
```

after all

```
var SONY = new Product();
SONY.is_active; // true;
SONY.someOtherThing; //undefined
```

How can i change properties of `Product` later ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Product` is being used as a *constructor function*. When you use a function as a constructor function (via the `new` operator), it does this:

1. `new` creates a new, blank object, and assigns `FunctionName.prototype` as the object's *prototype*.
2. `new` calls your constructor function with `this` referring to that new object.
3. (In the normal case.) The result of the `new` expression is a reference to that new object.

So what your code is doing in the `Product` function is assigning properties to the object created via `new`. If you want to add to that object, you simply add to it:

```
var p = new Product();
p.someOtherThing = "some value";
```

If you want to create properties on the prototype, you assign those to the `Product.prototype` object.

```
Product.prototype.someCommonProperty = "some value";
```

When you refer to a property on an object, the JavaScript engine first looks at the object itself to see if it has the property. If it doesn't, the engine looks at the object's *prototype* to see if it has the property (and then the prototype's prototype, etc.). So adding properties to the prototype makes them available via the instances that use that prototype.

So let's look at your `Product`:

```
var Product = function(){  
   this.is_active = true,
   this.is_bom_enabled = false;
};

var p = new Product();
```

The object that `p` refers to has it's *own* properties `is_active` and `is_bom_enabled`. They don't come from its prototype. If we do this:

```
Product.prototype.someCommonProperty = "some value";
```

...then if you do `p.someCommonProperty`, the engine first looks to see if `p` has its own property `someCommonProperty` and, since it doesn't, the engine looks to the prototype. Since the prototype has it, it gets the value from there.

Note that use of properties from prototypes is assymmetrical: *Getting* a property value from an object will use the prototype's version, but *setting* a property value will always set it on the actual object. So:

```
console.log(p.someCommonProperty); // "some value" -- from the prototype
p.someCommonProperty = "foo";      // Adds the property to `p`, doesn't change the prototype
console.log(p.someCommonProperty); // "foo" -- from `p`, not the prototype
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Currently i am using prototype to add new properties.

Comment: @Red: Just note that they will be common properties, used by all instances.

Comment: Crowder Yes i understand that.All functions are shared and they need to be .. individual properties setting to the object (basically i am only creating one instance of Product).

Comment: @Red: If you only ever have one copy of `Product`, there's no need to use a constructor function at all: `var product = { is_active: true, is_bom_enabled: false };` and then `product.someNewProperty = "some value";`. (Note I've made `product` lower case; normally, initially-caped symbols are constructor functions. It's just convention, though.)

Comment: Crowder, Yes i understand that, However i feel that its better to have constructor function,because the product Bill Of material contains Products which is exactly a `Product` ( currently i dont have this feature, but i am sure i will have to alter my source code ). Thanks for your suggestion, i will change it to small letters.

Comment: @Red: Well, if you use `Product` as a constructor, I'd keep it the way it is. Best,

Answer (score 1):

```
var Product = function(){
    this.is_active = true,
    this.is_bom_enabled = false;
};

Product.prototype.someOtherThing = value;

var SONY = new Product();
SONY.is_active; // true;
SONY.someOtherThing; //value
```